# What happens when this SE site graduates?

Tags: discussion

Earlier this summer there was a grape in the vine saying this site was going to graduate this Fall and it dawned on me now. What does that even mean? I've read the reputation requirements for some privileges go up and we aren't evaluated monthly on our performance on Area 51 anymore. The beta sign goes away, but what else is there that happens upon graduation? Someone makes a code challenge asking you to print out "Happy Graduation Day Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!"?

Comment: This sounds like it's a question for meta.stackexchange.com, [where it's already sort of answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/201409).

Comment: Note that if the person from which you heard we'll be graduating in the fall was named Geobits, it is not true.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Wow. Asking this on Meta SE was my 2nd thought. Now I see I should have. It looks like this is a process in review so it might not hurt trying to ask it there even if in a few months the answer might be completely different than if it was answered today or tomorrow..

Comment: Also see this: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5834/14215